# How to restart a node in redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a redis cluster with 5 instances.

Suddenly one instance started to  keep raising 'used_memory_rss' currently the 'mem_fragmentation_ratio' is higher than 650, so I want to restart only that instance without breaking any cluster setting.

Currently, the cluster doesn't have any data, I flushed them all. Also it's kind of idle now, no connections for them. So downtime would be fine.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the specific instance port folder for redis.conf (node information) file to restart that instance.
Simply re-run the command

```
../redis-server redis.conf
```

The current node will re-join the cluster.